# Can I use grease pencil in game engine

Tags: game-engine, grease-pencil

Is it possible to draw and clear grease pencil real-time during/over blender game engine gameplay?

Comment: no, using the grease pencil in a game is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since the game engine does not support drawing with grease pencil while the game engine is running, I made a script to draw on the camera in the game engine.

To use the script, enter it into the text editor and name it *grease_pencil.py*. You could call it anything, but it must end in *`.py`* to work as a module.

[image: Text editor]

Add a *Python* controller to an *Always* sensor, with true level triggering enabled, on any object. Change the python controller's *Execution Method* to *Module* and set its source to *grease_pencil.draw* or whatever you named it only without the *.py* and followed by *.draw* (draw is the name of the function we are calling).

[image: Always sensor and Python controller]

Press <kbd>P</kbd>, in the game engine, and click and drag to draw.

[image: Drawing in the game engine]

The complete script.

```
import bge

color = (.9, 0, 0)
lines = []

def position():
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    camera = scene.active_camera

    x, y = bge.logic.mouse.position

    vec = camera.worldPosition - camera.getScreenVect(x, y)
    vec = vec * camera.worldOrientation * camera.world_to_camera

    return vec

def mouse_just_down():
    return bge.logic.mouse.events[bge.events.LEFTMOUSE] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED

def mouse_down():
    return bge.logic.mouse.events[bge.events.LEFTMOUSE] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE

def mouse_moving():
    return bge.logic.mouse.events[bge.events.MOUSEX] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE or \
        bge.logic.mouse.events[bge.events.MOUSEY] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE

def draw():
    if mouse_just_down():
        lines.append([position()])

    if mouse_down() and mouse_moving():
        lines[-1].append(position())

    for line in lines:
        prev = None
        for vec in line:
            if prev:
                bge.render.drawLine(prev, vec, color)                
            prev = vec
```

Answer (score 0):

upbge 0.3.0 branch has this capability (real 3d grease pencil strikes)